# Allow TextView to be outside of Screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I want my TextView to be allowed out of the screen horizontally (And also disable horizontal scroll bars), such as this:

[image]

However, the XML I have right now causes it to automatically fit inside the parent, such as this:

[image]

**Code**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello1"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello2"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello3"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

How do I change my code to get the layout displayed in the **First Image**? Simply just cut off the textview if it goes out of the parent.

**EDIT: Tried LinearLayout. It didn't work either**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello1"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello2"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello3"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:singleLine="true"   on textView might do the trick

Comment: Oh yes it did! Very simple solution! Post it as an answer please. It might help someone else too @the stalker btw it shows "...." after cutting off the text. How do I stop that from happening?

Comment: After cutting off the text it displays "....". How do I stop that?

Comment: Android clips text views in onDraw and does not take flags such a as clipChildren into account. You may need to add some padding etc to make it display everything.

Comment: @JohanShogun Padding? Could you provide an example please. The solution provided by thestalker works but now it shows some "..." in place of the hidden text. So close!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using This attribute on your 3 TextView

```
android:maxLines="1"
```

After setting maxLines="1" I got this result

[image]

Comment: Btw does this work for left side as well? I mean, if I'm to cut off Hello1 will that work?

Comment: It doesnt work for left side view :( I want to cut off hello1 if the marginRight is set

Comment: Its a hack it will not work for left side because it just make sure everything is displayed in one line and the left over part is hidden , can you tell me what effect you are trying to achieve , why you wan't to cut first textView

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and set orientation to horizontal.

EDITED

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello1"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello2"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="30px"
        android:id="@+id/tab3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello3"
        android:textColor="#1089F9"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm worried I won't be able to use the android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tab1" attributes if I use LinearLayout. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: And looks like LinearLayout doesnt create the result I want either. Still fits the children in the parent view

Comment: If you set orientation to horizontal, view will automatically be set to right

Comment: Did you try horizontal orientation?

Comment: Nah I didnt try that, should I replace my RelativeLayout with that?